# sum of products Boolean algebra simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have a question that states the following:

```
Use algebraic manipulation to show that for three input variables x1 , x2 , and x3
∑(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) = x1 + x2 + x3
```

I'm assuming it wants the minimum sum of products to prove its equality to `x1 + x2 + x3 (or x + y + z)`. This is what I've narrowed it down to so far: `y'z + x'y + xz' + xyz`.

However, I'm unable to understand which property's will reduce this to just x + y + z (or again, x1 + x2 + x3).

Answer (score 1):

In the list of terms 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 only term 0 is missing. Term 0 corresponds to a conjunction of the three inverted variables. Therefore, you can look at the inverse function and invert it to get the desired function:

$F = (F')' = (x' y' z')'$

The first of [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) states:

> The negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.

This leads to:

$F = x + y + z$